# implementing OrientationEventListener to help camera issues without CameraInfo?

Tags: android

I need to implement an `OrientationEventListener` to get the camera working correctly. Google posted a sample implementation of `onOrientationChanged` that looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
     mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
    }
```

But I'm building against API level 8, so I don't have `CameraInfo`. How can I accomplish a similar thing as the above without `CameraInfo`?

Comment: so it is only for the back facing camera? Then just use the `else` part and you can skip everything about the `CameraInfo` part..

Answer (score 2):

Although the orientation changes, I find I have to also change the camera preview to match, if you want full-screen images on rotation, so I use a similar method but in the onLayout() method of a camera surface view like so:

```
/*
 * This class provides the surface for the camera.
 */
public class CameraSurfaceView extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        if (changed)
        {               

            final int width = right - left;
            final int height = bottom - top;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null)
            {
                Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                switch (display.getRotation())
                {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                        previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                        previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                        previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                        previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                        previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                        previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                        break;
                }                                    
            }

            final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;

            cameraView.layout(0, height - scaledChildHeight, width, height);

        }
    }
```

}

This has worked for me on an HTC Desire using Android API 8 (Android 2.2).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
   if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;

   int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
         .getRotation();
   int degrees = 0;
   switch (rotation) {
     case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
   }

   parameters.setRotation(degrees );
   mcamera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**
Refer the Camera app source code to know how they handled it. This link is to the latest source. Can go back in revisions and see for 2.2 version.
[Camera source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/camera;)

**EDIT :** Here is the link to one of those revisions nearby 2.2 release. Search `onOrientationChanged` in this file: [Camera src](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/Camera.java;h=013ff7c665b86e06da23a0a1396612d1e4a5ab04;hb=e453bdb87ca7eb4e05b817774124731237a3d437)

Comment: Refer the `Camera` app source code. This link is to the latest source. Can go back in revisions and see for 2.2 version.  http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/camera;